# Is it correct to define two listen (80 and 443) under same nginx server?

Tags: nginx, ssl, web-server, https, httpd.conf

Is it correct to define both `listen` (80 **and 443**) under same `server {}` like this ?

The other method would be to define two separate `server{}` for each port which I know would be OK.

```
server {

    listen       80 default_server;
    server_name  example.com;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location / {

    }


    listen example.com:443 ssl; # <<< !!!

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; 
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; 
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;         
}
```

Comment: See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#single_http_https_server) from the official documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I remember, yes it is. Also says so in the documentation (link below):

> ### A single HTTP/HTTPS server
>
> It is possible to configure a single server that handles both 
>   HTTP and HTTPS requests:
>
> ```
> server {
>    listen              80;
>    listen              443 ssl;
>    server_name         www.example.com;
>    ssl_certificate     www.example.com.crt;
>    ssl_certificate_key www.example.com.key;
>    ...
> }
> ```

src: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html

Answer (score 6):

It is allowed to listen on multiple ports on the same `server` block, but it depends on your objective if you want to do it.

Personally I use the following setup when I have the following set of domains and I want to use `https://www.example.com` as the main domain:

```
http://example.com
https://example.com
http://www.example.com
https://www.example.com
```

`server` block for `example.com` ports 80 and 443:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    ssl_certificate ...;
    ssl_certificate_key ...;

    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

This `server` block redirects all requests coming into `http://example.com` or `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com`.

Then, there are two blocks total for `http://www.example.com` and `https://www.example.com`:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name www.example.com;

    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name www.example.com;

    ssl_certificate ...;
    ssl_certificate_key ...;

    ... rest of config ...
}
```